# In Javascript 'this' is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, dom, this, dom-events, window-resize

I've created a method, i.e. `connectEvent()` inside an object called `FL` and it has properties including `event`, `el` and `fn`.
When I use the method and then try to access `this.el`, the `console.log()` says `undefined` even though I have assigned `window` to it `el`.

Why is `this.el` undefined? Isn't `this` supposed to refer to the object `FL`?

JS:

```
var FL = {
    connectEvent : function(params) {

        var params = params || {};

        if (params.el.addEventListener) {
            params.el.addEventListener(params.event, params.fn, false);
        } else if (params.el.attachEvent) {
            params.el.attachEvent('on' + params.event, params.fn);
        } else {
            params.el['on' + params.event] = params.fn;
        }
    }
};

FL.connectEvent({ 
    event: 'resize', 
    el: window, 
    fn: function() {
        console.log('start on resize');

        console.log('wat is this.el? ', this.el);

        console.log('end on resize');
    } 
});
```

Comment: this is a common gotcha in JS. The quick fix would be to do `params.fn.bind(this)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because in event listeners (and commonly in most callbacks) the function's "this", changes. In event listeners it's usually the element that triggers the event, in your case, this is actually your "el". To work around this you can do:

```
var FL = {
    connectEvent : function(params) {

        var params = params || {};
        var listener = function () {
            params.fn();
        };

        if (params.el.addEventListener) {
            params.el.addEventListener(params.event, listener, false);
        } else if (params.el.attachEvent) {
            params.el.attachEvent('on' + params.event, listener);
        } else {
            params.el['on' + params.event] = listener;
        }
    }
};

FL.connectEvent({ 
    event: 'resize', 
    el: window, 
    fn: function() {
        console.log('start on resize');

        console.log('wat is this.el? ', this.el);

        console.log('end on resize');
    } 
});
```

That way the listener function inherits the context it's created in, so it has access to params and calling params.fn() would preserve it's "this". If you want to also get the arguments of the event callback you can do:

```
var listener = function () {
     params.fn.apply(params, arguments);
};
```

The last one is equivalent to using:

```
var listener = params.fn.bind(params);
```

, but also works in older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems, First your never assigning to `this` in that function. So `this` will have no el property. Instead your assigning to a local variable `params` which is closed off to anyone outside that function. (Your also redefining it with the `var` statement. Best to remove it since you've already have it defined in the parameters of the function).

Second, You attempting to use `this` in a function which gets called from an event listener. When an event listener calls a callback function the context is set to something else (Depends on implementation / browser) instead of the original instance (this is the most common case). There for `this` references something else.

One approach would be to make `connectEvent` a proper constructor and use the `new` keyword and drop the use of `params` in favor of instance properties (`this`).

However, in your case it looks more likely to just force the context of the callback using `bind()`

```
var context = {
  el: params.el
};
params.el.addEventListener(params.event, params.fn.bind(context), false);

params.el.attachEvent('on' + params.event, params.fn.bind(context));
```

That way when the callback function does get called `this` will refer to the new object created called `context`.